# Programmatically Select Marker to Navigate To Location Google_Maps_Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-flutter

I am trying to develop a user experience where the user is provided a list of venues to travel to, and upon selecting one of those locations, I want it to

1. Add a marker to the map
2. Show an info window
3. Provide the option to navigate to the
   location.

I was able to use the information [from this PR](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2181) (that has no official documentation it seems) to go from this:

[image: Before use of PR]

To this:

[image: Functionality after using the showMarkerInfo function]

However, showing the marker info still does not make the given marker "active". When I select the marker, the functionality of the plugin actually displays options for navigating to the given location on the bottom right, like this:

[image: Functionality of the Google_Maps_Flutter plugin when the marker is actually selected.]

What I would like is for the selection of the venue at the bottom of the list to automatically display all three criteria in the third image with one press. That is, once again:

1. The marker of the location
2. The info window
3. The option to navigate to that location.

Right now, a user has to click the entry from the list at the bottom, and then rather un-intuitively *click the marker on the map* in order for the navigation options to appear.

**How would I go about programatically launching the "on-tap" event that happens when the user "taps" the marker when selecting an item from the list?**

Here is my current code for changing the viewport, adding a marker, and showing the info window:

```
Future<void> goSomewhere(id, name, distance, address, lat, lng) async {
final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 14.0)));
setState(() {
  _markers.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(id),
    position: LatLng(lat, lng),
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
      title: name,
      snippet: address,
    ),
    onTap: () {
      //_pageController.jumpToPage(i);
    },
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
  ));
  print(MarkerId(id));
  controller.showMarkerInfoWindow(MarkerId(id));
});
```

}

Right now, my solution does add the marker and show the info window, but comes up short giving the user options for navigating to the location *unless* the user clicks the marker. In its current state, I've built something that makes for a very sub-optimal user experience.

I've tried alternative solutions like [highlighting the marker](https://gist.github.com/sh0umik/05ab4cad0d4604056e715551d67cb063), but it does not quite have the functionality I'm looking for. I do not understand what event occurs within the plugin that "selects" the marker on-tap, and all attempts I've found that "programmatically" select the marker do some version of highlighting it. Simply some direction as to where to look to find out what event is being launched when the marker is clicked would be helpful.

Comment: I really don't believe you can programmatically simulate the "tap" of the marker - it will only respond to the user's physical "tap".  And also, can you programmatically make the little directions/open maps icon pop up?  I don't believe you can do that either (at least, there's certainly no method available on the map controller or marker object to do it) - I guess it's just an inherent part of the map functionlity.  Maybe your best bet to have an "Open in Maps" button at the top of your list (under the map) that users can click on (if they haven't actually highlighted the marker)

Comment: There are a couple of different "maps launcher" flutter plug-ins (I've used this one successfully https://pub.dev/packages/maps_launcher).  I'm kind of in the same boat as you with a handful of different things I've wanted to try and achieve within Flutter - get very close to the end goal and then just that last hurdle you can't get over ...... by all means try posting questions within the flutter community / github - people are always very responsive and helpful - but all the questions I can find like the one you are asking, are saying that it can't be done

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback! To be honest, I got super discouraged because the post got heavily down-voted. I wasn't sure how else to ask what I was looking for, or how to even accomplish what I wanted to do. I ended up re-designing my user experience a bit - and I did it *exactly* how you're describing. I plan on answering this question with my answer if you're interested! My whole flutter journey has been exactly how you've described, so it's nice to hear someone else that can empathize going through it, too. I'll check out the Flutter community / github as well - thanks!

Comment: That's cool.  Sorry I couldn't help (but glad I could help a little bit!) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't come to a complete answer, but I wanted to share my experience in case anyone else runs into this problem and feels stuck. By going through the Flutter Github / asking around the forums, I was able to get three key take-aways:

1. As far as I know, there is no way to simulate the "tap" of the marker in Flutter. I tried looking at [the Kotlin/Swift APIs for platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to write some of this functionality myself, but to be honest it was pretty far out of my wheelhouse and I burned a lot of time on it. This also might result in having to go through the approval process with the nice people at Google for my changes to be accepted, but it's not time that I personally have right now.
2. I found a package called [Maps Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/maps_launcher) that was also mentioned by Craig in the comments section that has the ability to launch the Maps application by two methods - Launch by Query, and Launch by Latitude/Longitude. This functionality is effectively identical to the functionality you get when you tap the marker and then select one of the two maps options on the bottom right.
3. I discovered that the primary difference between the two
   icons that you get when you tap the marker is that one launches
   directions by query, and the other by latitude and longitude - just
   like the Maps Launcher plugin.

So with these three pieces of information, I redesigned the application to go from this:

[image: Original Experience]

To look like this:

[image: New experience with MAP launcher]

Now a user:

1. Selects a location from the list.
2. Selecting a new location adds a marker and shows the location's infowindow
3. Can hit the button on the right to navigate to the given location.

In my opinion, this experience is much more clean - there is no ambiguity between the two maps options you can launch (by query vs by lat/long) when selecting a marker, as a button that launches the maps icon is now on the Listview.  This also allows you to navigate to each marker pretty easily just by clicking it in the listview, and then deciding whether or not you want navigation directions by pressing the button on the right.

The code for adding this to your app is pretty simple:

```
new Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: venues.length,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                  color: _selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == index
                      ? Colors.greenAccent
                      : Colors.white,
                  child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  goSomewhere(
                      venues[index].venueId,
                      venues[index].name,
                      venues[index].distance,
                      venues[index].formattedAddress,
                      double.parse(venues[index].latitude),
                      double.parse(venues[index].longitude)
                  );
                  _onSelected(index);
                },
                title: Text(
                  venues[index]
                      .name /*+ ' and ' + venues[index].formattedAddress*/,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
                trailing: Container(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue,

                  ),
                      onPressed: () => MapsLauncher.launchQuery(
                          venues[index].formattedAddress),
                      child: Icon(Icons.assistant_navigation),
                )),
                subtitle: Text(venues[index].formattedAddress),
              ));
            },
          ))
```

It's a subtle difference, but I've done some testing and my (small) group of users seem to like this much more as it's much more intuitive. Also, the location they get in their Maps application has a recognizable address regardless of which button they press.

While this is not a "full" answer to the original question, I hope that this might help someone on their Flutter journey to stick to the framework - despite some of these early hurdles.

Answer (score 7):

You beat me to it! I was about to answer this question earlier but when I reloaded the page, I saw you already answered it. Though it appears that you already found the solution to your issue, I thought of posting my answer here still. Please see below:

I couldn't find a way to programmatically display the map toolbar(options for navigating to the given location on the bottom right) as you really need to click a marker to show it. But here's a workaround that I thought would fit your use case:

1. Disable the map toolbar by setting `mapToolbarEnabled: false` in `GoogleMap()` widget. (The map toolbar only works for Android anyway)
2. Create a custom map toolbar that launches [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started?authuser=0#search-action) and [Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) URLs from the app.  That toolbar only shows when you select a location from the listview or when you click a marker.

I used the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/install) package to launch the Google Maps and Directions URLs.

```
 Future<void> _launchUrl(bool isDir, double lat, double lon) async {
    String url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$lon';

    if (isDir) {
      url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Googleplex&destination=$lat,$lon';
    }

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Then I used the method above on a custom Map toolbar widget

```
Widget mapToolBar() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.map),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            _launchUrl(false, {your_lat}, {your_lng})
          },
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.directions),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            _launchUrl(true, {your_lat}, {your_lng};
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Then put the custom widget in a `Stack` widget with the `Googlemap()` widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 7,
          child: Stack(children: [
            GoogleMap(
                  .
                  .
                  .
              ),
            mapToolBar()
          ]),
        ),
        _pageViewBuilder(context),
      ]),
    );
  }
```