# Flutter: How to always show google map toolbar buttons without even selecting marker?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, maproute

In flutter app i've created map with [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package, and placed a Marker, selecting marker shows two buttons at the bottom right of map, but i want those buttons to be shown always by defauld even without clicking on marker, (basically i only need navigation button of toolbar so that i can show routs between marker and current location of user), is this possible?

Comment: If you always want to show those 2 buttons either click on marker or not you just put those buttons and map inside stack widget inside the scaffold.

Comment: @SumitKumawat, i haven't written any code for those buttons, those buttons are provided by google_maps_flutter package by default on selection of marker, so i don't find any way to do that, it may be possible that i haven't undrstuder your suggestion, if it true then please show me with an example. Note: I have also tried to edit original package code to change condition of appearance of buttons but couldn't do that, all i want is that when i open map at that time marker should be selected and direction button should be shown so that i can navigate to from current location, please help thanks

Comment: @AnilShrivastav, the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040228/programmatically-select-marker-to-navigate-to-location-google-maps-flutter) might help.