# google_maps_flutter refresh InfoWindow

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

**google_maps_flutter**

Is there a way to programmatically display/hide the **InfoWindow**? Maybe "*selecting*" a marker?

When I move the camera to a different marker, **the previous marker still is selected, therefore Infowindow is not updated.**

I have failed on attempts trying to null InfoWindow property, setting to empty string, etc.

I have this code below to select a marker. This works perfectly when user taps a marker on the map.  But when you try to navigate to a marker on the map through code (e.g. calling selectMarker), I can´t find a way to programmatically display the InfoWindow of the tapped marker (and hide it on the previously selected marker).

```
  void **selectMarker**(String markerId, bool requiresCameraPositioning) async {

var previouslySelectedMarker = _localSelectedMarkerId;
print ('x: method:selectMarker, markerId:${markerId}, requiresCameraPositioning${requiresCameraPositioning}, localSelectedMarkerId:${_localSelectedMarkerId}, requiresCameraPositioning${requiresCameraPositioning}');
// Unselect the previously selected marker

_localSelectedMarkerId = markerId;
final markerItem = markerController.markers.firstWhere(
      (marker) => marker.id == markerId,
  orElse: () => throw Exception('Marker not found'),
);

if (requiresCameraPositioning) {
  mapControllerManager.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(markerItem.position.latitude, markerItem.position.longitude),
        zoom: 15,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

_updateMarkerIcons(); // Refresh markers to reflect the selection


var selectedMarker = _markers.firstWhere((element) => element.markerId == _localSelectedMarkerId);
// show modal
_showModalBottomSheet(context, markerId);
```

}

void _updateMarkerIcons() {
setState(() {

```
  Set<Marker> updatedMarkers = {};
  for (var markerItem in markerController.markers) {
    bool isSelected = markerItem.id == _localSelectedMarkerId;

    updatedMarkers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(markerItem.id),
        position: markerItem.position,
        **infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: markerItem.title),** I have tried multiple things here
        icon: determineMarkerIcon(markerItem),
        onTap: () {
          selectMarker(markerItem.id, false); // Call _selectMarker here instead
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  _markers = updatedMarkers;
});
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically Select Marker to Navigate To Location Google\_Maps\_Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040228/programmatically-select-marker-to-navigate-to-location-google-maps-flutter)